# How to change iPython error highlighting color

Tags: ipython

I'm using IPython with iterm2 in macOS. I had never had issues before with the color scheme, but this time when an exception occurs, it highlights certain parts in a color combination that I find very hard to read. I've tried with different color setups in iterm and also adjusting `highlighting_style` and `colors` in the `ipython_config.py` file, without much luck. I've seen there is an option to set specific colors `highlighting_style_overrides` but I haven't been lucky finding the right pygments option for this.

See `Position` below. This is the best contrast setup I've achieved, I still find hard it to read without focusing.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Your problem resolved yet?

Comment: No, I haven't been able to find a solution yet

Comment: Workaround: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/13756#issue-1370412994

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**NOTE:** Use Evan Grim's answer below for a persistent config without touching package files.

---

There is an open issue regarding this: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/13446

Here is the commit which introduced this change:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/commit/3026c205487897f6874b2ff580fe0be33e36e033

To get the file path on your system, run the following:

```
import IPython, os
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(IPython.__file__), 'core/ultratb.py')
```

Finally, open the file and look for:

```
style = stack_data.style_with_executing_node(style, "bg:ansiyellow")
```

For the time being, you can manually patch it by changing `bg:ansiyellow` to something that works best given your color scheme, e.g. `bg:ansired` or `bg:#ff0000`.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using Evan Grim's answer instead. Changes to packages' python files will be lost if the package (ipython) is ever updated, or if you install ipython in a second virtual environment, etc.

Comment: Correct; added a note.

Answer (score 15):

Here's an option you can drop in your `ipython_config.py` to duck punch in a better background color:

```py
try:
    from IPython.core import ultratb
    ultratb.VerboseTB._tb_highlight = "bg:ansired"
except Exception:
    print("Error patching background color for tracebacks, they'll be the ugly default instead")
```

Verified to work with `IPython` version `8.7.0`